# Manejo de llamadas

Tags: java, android

Estaba realizando una aplicación que realiza llamadas con el siguiente codigo

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
intent.setData(Uri.parse(“tel:numerodetelefono”));    
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Hay alguna manera de saber el tiempo que duro la llamada, no el tiempo desde que empezó a llamar si no en el que la otra persona atendió. Y algún método para cortar la llamada realizada?

Comment: Cortar la llamada no es permitido en Android sin privilegios de sistema. Para recibir información sobre duración de llamada o estado de teléfono puedes usar un `android.telephony.PhoneStateListener`.

Comment: Me parece que sería dificil obtener el tiempo de inicio desde que se inicia la atención de la llamada, pero para obtener el tiempo desde el inicio y al colgar puedes usar un Broadcastreceiver y detectar cuando se cuelga.

Comment: @StefanNolde  Hay aplicaciones en la tienda de google que cortan la llamada como por ejemplo Call Timer

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti No dije que no es posible, dije que no es permitido sin privilegios de sistema. Yo también lo hago.

Comment: @StefanNolde Pero utilizando que codigo o de que manera lo haces?

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti lo hago en una manera que tiene mucho potencial de abuso con el conocimiento y acuerdo de mi cliente y la opción de no permitirlo para cada usuario de la aplicación. No me agrada la idea de proveer una solución lista para uso aquí. El acceso a llamadas directas esta restringido en Android por buenas razones. Te gustaría si tu telefono hace llamadas a números premium  en la noche, luego colgando y tu ni siquiera te das cuenta hasta te llega la boleta?

Comment: @StefanNolde El código para realizar la llamada lo tengo, lo que no se es como obtener el tiempo que duro la llamada y como cortar. No es ese el fin que comentar el uso que necesito darle, lo que necesito es ingresar una lista de números e indicarle el tiempo que dure la llamada, es para realizar unas pruebas

Answer (score 4):

Para medir el tiempo de llamadas (entrantes y salientes) puedes usar código de Gabe Sechan, que publicó una clase abstracta `PhoneCallReceiver`. Lo encuentras [en su respuesta aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878840/android-incoming-outgoing-calls). No olvides de darle tu voto si su código te ayuda.

En tu Actividad o Servicio haces un `@Override`:

```
private BroadcastReceiver br = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    br = new PhonecallReceiver() {
        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallStarted(String number, Date start) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallPickup(String number, Date start) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(String number, Date start) {
            // llamada saliente - guarda numero y fecha en un registro a tu gusto
        }

        @Override
        protected void onIncomingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(String number, Date start, Date end) {
             // llamada saliente terminado. Busca el numero en tu registro y calcula la diferencia de las fechas
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMissedCall(String number, Date start) {

        }
    };
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE");
    registerReceiver(br,filter);
        //        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ring "+incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

No voy a compartir artefactos hechos que permiten la cortada de llamadas sin intervención de usuario por la misma razón que no paso armas de fuego a menores, ni los dejo no atendido en publico.  El código fácilmente podría ser cambiado para **hacer** llamadas sin intervención de usuario. Por razones de seguridad y para evitar abuso (por ejemplo en forma de malware) Google no soporta hacks de este tipo.

Comment: No entiendo porque seguís diciendo sin la intervención del usuario. Lo que estoy necesitando es una aplicacion que se le cargue una lista de números y el tiempo de cada llamada y con un botón empiece el proceso de llamados, obviamente como son varios los números a llamar necesito que entre llamados se corte para poder realizar la próxima llamada

Comment: Ya, y el usuario lo puede cortar. Por el boton de la app por defecto en el dispositivo. el código arriba registra que se cortó la llamada.

Comment: La idea es que si tenes que hacer 100 llamadas el proceso sea automático, cargas los 100 números, el tiempo de cada llamada y empiece el ciclo. No entiendo porque pones lo de las llamadas premium en la noche si la aplicacion estaría abierta en todo momento @StefanNolde

Comment: Entonces tienes que solicitar un nuevo privilegio de google para permitir "BULK_DIRECT_CALLING", que el usuario tiene que permitir cuando instala la app. Por favor entiende que no dudo que **tu** quieres hacer es legitimo, pero dudo que es sabio de compartir un hack que 1. puede dejar funcionar en cualquier actualisación de seguridad de Android y 2. tiene un tremendo potencial de ser usado en malware. Me lo podría haber hecho más fácil en simplemente decirte que no se puede, pero no miento.